# Prove: $ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)^2 \mathrm{\,d}x \ge 4$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

[image]

I need to prove the following integral inequality: $\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)^2 \mathrm{\,d}x \ge 4$. I have tried to use Hölder's integral inequality but have no use. Can you help me to prove that?

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with orthogonal functions you can prove it as follows: Let $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_2(x)=\sqrt {12} (x-\frac 1 2)$. Then $f_1$ and $f_2$ form an orthonormal set in $L^{2}(0,1)$ and the inner product of $f$ with these functions are $1$ and $\sqrt 3$. Hence $\|f\|^{2} \geq 1^{2}+(\sqrt3 )^{2}=4$

Comment: You can just expand $\int_0^{1} (f(x)-f_1(x)-\sqrt 3 f_2(x))^{2}$ (which is non-negative ) to get the conclusion (without any knowledge of orthonormal systems) but this would like misterious.

Comment: How do you know f_1(x) and f_2(x) ?

Comment: @129492  You get $f_1$ and $f_2$ by applying Gram -Schmidt process to the functions $\{1,x\}$. (The person who thought of this question is very likely to have used my argument).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (which is essentially same as Kabo Murphy's one):

For any $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\int_{0}^{1}(f(x) - (ax + b))^{2}dx \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2} - 2a \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx - 2b\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{1}(ax+b)^{2}dx\geq 0\\
\Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2}dx \geq 2a + 2b -\frac{a^{2}}{3} - ab - b^{2}
$$
and
$$
2a + 2b - \frac{a^{2}}{3} - ab - b^{2} = - \left( b - \frac{a+2}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{a^{2} + 4a + 4}{4} - \frac{a^{2}}{3} + 2a\\ = - \left( b- \frac{a+2}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{12}(a-6)^{2} + 4
$$
so we can take $a = 6, b = 4$ and get the desired result.

Comment: What prompted you to start from the inequality $\int\limits_0^1(f(x)-(ax+b))^2 dx \ge 0$?

Comment: @Alexdanut It is hard to say but the fact that $\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ are given motivates me to try this.

Comment: Thank you ! <3 <3 <3